# Keep calling activity and clear other activities before that

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back-stack, taskstackbuilder

I am calling activities in the following order A>B>C>D, now I want to call Activity A and clear B and C but keep D. I am calling A with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`. But all the activities apart from A is getting cleared. Any body has any idea how to clear B and C and keep D>A.

Comment: You can't just call finish in B and C if you don't need them anymore?

Comment: I need it until I call A from D

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html  try reading meaning of those flags, you will probably figure out when to use which one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move A to the top (from D) by doing this in D:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

There aren't any simple flags you can use to get rid of B and C. I would suggest that you have B and C register a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for a specific ACTION. After you launch A from D, you can then send a broadcast `Intent` that will cause B and C to finish themselves. For example, in B and C do this:

```
// Declare receiver as member variable
BroadcastReceiver exitReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
        // This Activity is no longer needed, finish it
        finish();
    }
}
```

in `onCreate()` register the receiver:

```
registerReceiver(exitReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_EXIT));
```

don't forget to unregister the receiver in `onDestroy()`!

In D, when you launch A, send a broadcast `Intent` containing ACTION_EXIT to make B and C finish, like this:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_EXIT));
```

Answer (score -2):

Add this in your manifest for Class B, C.

```
<activity
android:name=".AnyActivity"
android:noHistory="true" />
```